# VNC and mDNS: Connection Refused

Tags: networking, vnc

I'm trying to access a Pi 4B+ with a dynamically-assigned IP address. I can VNC to the Pi using the (current) IP address, and I can hit it with no problem with Firefox, ssh or ping using the address `raspberrypi.local`, but when I try to connect to that address with VNC Viewer I get the message **The connection was refused by the computer**. How do I set up my Pi so I can VNC to it without editing the connection every time I reboot the Pi?

Comment: I can connect to mine with `MilliwaysPi4.local`. You need to provide more details of what you are doing and settings which don't work.

Comment: custom port perhaps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. VNC supports multiple sessions, identifying each with a display number (which corresponds to a port number in the 5900+ range). I needed to include the display number in the address, like this: `raspberrypi.local:1`.

(You might think that default values would handle this transparently; for some reason, though, RealVNC Client defaults to display `0` while vncserver defaults to `1`, and so they miss each other in the dark.)